# Error Deserializing JSON data with DataContractSerializer in Silverlight 4

Tags: json, silverlight-4.0, deserialization, json-deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I am trying to deserialize JSON from a Web service to a complex object in Silverlight using the DataContractJsonSerializer. When the JSON data is minimal, I am having no issues but when the data is large, I am getting SerializationException with the message " *' is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when extraneous data is present after the JSON data.*"

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyComplexObject));

MyComplexObject object= (MyComplexObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(e.Result);
```

How do I get around this error without having to limit the size of JSON data transferred

Comment: This seems to indicate that there are invalid characters *after* the closing `}` of the JSON file. It doesn't mean you have to shorten it - just that there is invalid data. Try to investigate the JSON file you are receiving.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON causing this to break?

Comment: I am actually consuming a MVC Action URI in my Silverlight application. The MVC app serializes a complex object and converts it into JSON. The deserialization works when the number of complex records serialized is around 4000 but when it goes beyond that, the aforementioned error occurs. I have a sample JSON for a single object, but its too long to put it here. I will post it in the next comment.

Comment: Sample JSON               {"ID":1606167,"TxnDate":"\/Date(1430280000000)\/","Date":null,"Month":{"MonthNumber":6,"MonthName":""},"Year":2015,"GC":2154.0000,"AP":false,"Caller":{"ID":657,"Name":"SampleName"},"Customer":{"ID":28,"Name":"Sample Customer","CallerFk":null},"BS":{"ID":1,"Name":"ABCD"},"Sec":null,"SecName":"Sample 1","Months":6,"CustomerFK":28,"CallerFK":657,"BS":"B","CustName":"Sample Name 3","CallerName":Sample Name 4","CatalystFK":null},